# How to stop placeholder from transitioning back ? (CSS)

Tags: html, css, debugging, css-transitions, placeholder

I was trying to create an input field with a transition effect to the placeholder, for that I used a `<span>` tag to hold the placeholder and transitioned it using the `:focus` CSS selector
It works pretty well but the problem is after we input the text and click anywhere outside the input area/text field area, the placeholder transitions back and overlaps with the text inputted.
I want the placeholder to not transition back if the text area currently has text in it.
Also, there is one more issue that the text field doesn't get selected if the placeholder is clicked.
How can I clear these bugs?
I've provided the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Input</title>

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    #top-heading {
      padding: 1rem;
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    
    textarea {
      width: 85%;
      display: block;
      height: 10vh;
      margin: 1.5rem;
      margin-top: 0rem;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      font-size: large;
    }
    
    span {
      position: absolute;
      top: 6rem;
      padding-left: 2.7rem;
      color: rgb(121, 120, 120);
      font-size: larger;
    }
    
    textarea:focus~span {
      color: black;
      font-size: 1.091rem;
      transition: .6s ease;
      transform: translate3d(-1.15rem, -1.9rem, 2rem);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="top-heading">Input</h1>

  <textarea id="txt-input"></textarea>
  <span>Enter the input</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I doubt this can be done with pure CSS. Also use a `label` instead of `span` using the `for` attribute to associate the label with the form element

Comment: yea, making the changes you suggested clears the second issue I mentioned, thank you for the help,

Comment: @JonP Now, speaking about the transition part, If not with CSS then can adding Javascript make it work the way I've mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You need to give `transition: .6s ease;` property to span tag instead of `textarea:focus~span`.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/kjfc0z37/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Input</title>

    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
      }

      #top-heading {
        padding: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
      }

      textarea {
        width: 85%;
        display: block;
        height: 10vh;
        margin: 1.5rem;
        margin-top: 0rem;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        font-size: large;

      }

      span {
        position: absolute;
        top: 6rem;
        padding-left: 2.7rem;
        color: rgb(121, 120, 120);
        font-size: larger;
        transition: .6s ease;
      }

      textarea:focus~span {
        color: black;
        font-size: 1.091rem;

        transform: translate3d(-1.15rem, -1.9rem, 2rem);
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 id="top-heading">Input</h1>

    <textarea id="txt-input"></textarea>
    <span>Enter the input</span>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Yudiz Solutions, Although this ain't solving the issue I have mentioned, I am curious to know the difference between adding transition in a span tag and text field:focus~span.